# How can I put several extracted values from a Json in an array in Kusto?

Tags: kql

I'm trying to write a query that returns the vulnerabilities found by "Built-in Qualys vulnerability assessment" in log analytics.

It was all going smoothly I was getting the values from the properties Json and turning then into separated strings but I found out that some of the terms posses more than one value, and I need to get all of them in a single cell.

My query is like this right now

```
securityresources | where type =~ "microsoft.security/assessments/subassessments"
    | extend assessmentKey=extract(@"(?i)providers/Microsoft.Security/assessments/([^/]*)", 1, id), IdAzure=tostring(properties.id)
    | extend IdRecurso = tostring(properties.resourceDetails.id)
    | extend NomeVulnerabilidade=tostring(properties.displayName),
        Correcao=tostring(properties.remediation),
        Categoria=tostring(properties.category),
        Impacto=tostring(properties.impact),
        Ameaca=tostring(properties.additionalData.threat),
        severidade=tostring(properties.status.severity),
        status=tostring(properties.status.code),
        Referencia=tostring(properties.additionalData.vendorReferences[0].link),
        CVE=tostring(properties.additionalData.cve[0].link)
    | where assessmentKey == "1195afff-c881-495e-9bc5-1486211ae03f"
    | where status == "Unhealthy"
    | project IdRecurso, IdAzure, NomeVulnerabilidade, severidade, Categoria, CVE, Referencia, status, Impacto, Ameaca, Correcao
```

Ignore the awkward names of the columns, for they are in Portuguese.

As you can see in the "Referencia" and "CVE" columns, I'm able to extract the values from a specific index of the array, but I want all links of the whole array

Answer (score 0):

Without sample input and expected output it's hard to understand what you need, so trying to guess here...

I think that `summarize make_list(...) by ...` will help you (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makelist-aggfunction) to learn how to use `make_list`)

If this is not what you're looking for, please delete the question, and post a new one with minimal sample input (using [datatable operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/datatableoperator)), and expected output, and we'll gladly help.